# How to click HTML button in Python + Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I  am trying to simulate button click in Python using Selenium.

```
<li class="next" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><a href="www.abc.com">Next →</a></li>
```

The Python script is 
`driver.find_element_by_class_name('next').click()`.

This gives an error. Can someone suggest me how to simulate a button `class`?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the error you are getting? Please see [ask]

Comment: What error does it gives you? Provide a traceback call and also what you have done so far to try to solve it.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".next[role='button']"))).click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, 
since the clickable element is anchor element the answer is

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='http://www.google.com']").click();